# Pl / SQL Oracle helps to run a Date in Subquery

Tags: oracle, plsql

How could I get the date of the Maximum Value, by means of a subquery
I can't put the Date in the Main query because I would have to add it to the group by it would bring me a lot of data

Here is the Code:

```
  SELECT MAX (A1.VALOR) AS VALOR,
         (SELECT sq1.FECHA
            FROM VARIABLE_VALORES_SMEC sq1
           WHERE sq1.ID_AGENTE = A1.ID_AGENTE)
            MES,                                  -- {<-- Here is the Problem}
         (SELECT CODIGO_AGENTE
            FROM AGENTES
           WHERE ID_AGENTE = A1.ID_AGENTE)
            Agentess,
         (SELECT NOMBRE_AGENTE
            FROM AGENTES
           WHERE ID_AGENTE = A1.ID_AGENTE)
            Nombre_Agente
    FROM VARIABLE_VALORES_SMEC A1
   WHERE     A1.VALOR < '1'
         AND A1.VALOR != '0'
         AND A1.ID_AGENTE IN (SELECT C1.ID_AGENTE
                                FROM VARIABLE_VALORES_SMEC C1
                               WHERE A1.FECHA = C1.FECHA)
         AND A1.ID_AGENTE IN (SELECT B1.ID_AGENTE
                                FROM AGENTES B1
                               WHERE ID_CATEGORIA_AGENTE = 'AC006')
         AND (A1.FECHA BETWEEN (ADD_MONTHS (TO_DATE ( :FECHAIN, 'MM/DD/YYYY'),
                                            -1))
                           AND (LAST_DAY (
                                   ADD_MONTHS (
                                      TO_DATE ( :FECHAIN, 'MM/DD/YYYY'),
                                      -1))))
         AND A1.ID_VARIABLE LIKE '%_calc_total_pot@%'
GROUP BY ID_AGENTE
```

Comment: You should avoid repeating tags in the question title. Also, this seems to be about Oracle SQL not the PL/SQL programming language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Am I correct that you need (fecha) for maximum A1.VALOR?
If - yes, you can use the following query, or if - no, just replace A1.VALOR with the required column in keep() clause:

```
  SELECT MAX (A1.VALOR) AS VALOR,
         max(A1.FECHA)keep(dense_rank first order by A1.VALOR desc) MES, -- A1.VALOR is used here as sort key, replace it with what you want
         (SELECT CODIGO_AGENTE
            FROM AGENTES
           WHERE ID_AGENTE = A1.ID_AGENTE)
            Agentess,
         (SELECT NOMBRE_AGENTE
            FROM AGENTES
           WHERE ID_AGENTE = A1.ID_AGENTE)
            Nombre_Agente
    FROM VARIABLE_VALORES_SMEC A1
   WHERE     A1.VALOR < '1'
         AND A1.VALOR != '0'
         AND A1.ID_AGENTE IN (SELECT C1.ID_AGENTE
                                FROM VARIABLE_VALORES_SMEC C1
                               WHERE A1.FECHA = C1.FECHA)
         AND A1.ID_AGENTE IN (SELECT B1.ID_AGENTE
                                FROM AGENTES B1
                               WHERE ID_CATEGORIA_AGENTE = 'AC006')
         AND (A1.FECHA BETWEEN (ADD_MONTHS (TO_DATE ( :FECHAIN, 'MM/DD/YYYY'),
                                            -1))
                           AND (LAST_DAY (
                                   ADD_MONTHS (
                                      TO_DATE ( :FECHAIN, 'MM/DD/YYYY'),
                                      -1))))
         AND A1.ID_VARIABLE LIKE '%_calc_total_pot@%'
GROUP BY ID_AGENTE
```

Comment: Thank you very much friend, it was what I needed

Answer (score 1):

You can use `row_number` analytical function to fetch one record for which `value` is highest and use the `fecha` of that record. Use following sub query:

```
(Select fecha from
      (SELECT sq1.FECHA, row_number() over (order by sq1.value desc nulls last) as rn
        FROM VARIABLE_VALORES_SMEC sq1
       WHERE sq1.ID_AGENTE = A1.ID_AGENTE)
Where rn = 1) MES
```